# Why are the standard errors of these emmeans contrasts 100x lower than those of the emmeans themselves?

Tags: r, glm, emmeans

I'm getting results from a `glm` model that I can't understand.  In this model, Bond is a factor with three levels.  The `emmeans` of the three levels have large standard errors and wide confidence intervals.  There doesn't seem to be any significant distinction between the levels from this perspective.

However, when I look at some pairwise comparisons, the standard errors are 100x smaller, and two comparisons (A10 - A15 and A14 - A15) are actually significant at the 95% confidence level.  Is there any property of the data or the model that can explain this?

Apologies for my lack of statistical knowledge and inability to produce a reproducible example, as the data set has over 1,000 rows.  Many thanks in advance.

````
> emmeans(Model1, "Bond")

 Bonder emmean   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 A10     -6.75 21.6 Inf     -49.1      35.6
 A14     -6.48 21.6 Inf     -48.8      35.9
 A15     -6.12 21.6 Inf     -48.5      36.2

Results are averaged over the levels of: Spin, Type 
Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

> pairs(emmeans(Model1, "Bond"))

 contrast  estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 A10 - A14   -0.271 0.2579 Inf -1.049  0.5456 
 A10 - A15   -0.636 0.2591 Inf -2.453  0.0376 
 A14 - A15   -0.365 0.0674 Inf -5.416  <.0001 

Results are averaged over the levels of: Spin, Type 
Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to know for sure, but the most obvious reason would be that there's a strong positive correlation between the estimates. In general the variance of (`A-B`) is `Var(A)+Var(B)-2*Cov(A,B)`, so (for example) if `A`, `B`, `C` all had variances (and therefore std errors) of 1 and correlations (== covariances in this case) of 0.8 between all pairs; then the variance of any pairwise difference is is `1+1-2*0.8=0.4`, so the std dev would be 0.63.However, reducing the standard errors by two orders of magnitude would require a *very* strong correlation.

A related possibility is that this is a case of **complete separation** (which would lead to large coefficients and even larger standard errors, although I would typically expect these to be even larger (e.g. `|beta|>8`, SD>5*beta)

What is `cov2cor(vcov(Model))` ?

Comment: I agree. In addition, note that this is on the logit scale, and the EMMs correspond to extremely low predicted probabilities -- in the 0.001 range. To get a more direct idea of the covariances involved, do `EMM = emmeans(Model1, "Bond"); vcov(EMM); cov2cor(vcov(EMM))`

Comment: Thank you Ben and Russ for the useful advice.  When I looked at the results of that calculation and then at some of the emmeans for other variables, I found evidence of variance inflation.  I filtered the data to exclude two levels of the Type variable that had few rows and were zero inflated, and it led to much more understandable results.

Comment: That explains it!

Comment: I had the same problem when using `contrast`. I'm fitting a binomial regression with `glm`. My `SE` was way bigger than my `odds.ratio` in the `contrast` result, so I printed the emmeans related object and found out that the CI for one level was [0, 1], i.e. the full probability interval. For this specific level, all the values were 0. I just refitted my model without this level and all the SEs were lower than the `odds.ratio` as I would expect.

Comment: Probably "complete separation" - you could search for that on https://stats.stackexchange.com ...